# Plot Scipy ODE solution

Tags: matplotlib, scipy

I've been trying to solve a nonlinear ordinary differential equation numerically by using Scipy, in particular by the `scipy.integrate.RK23` command. It returns `<scipy.integrate._ivp.rk.RK23 at 0x7f2b1a908390>`. How can I plot the solution?

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**

As a simple example for testing:

```
import numpy
import scipy.integrate

t0=0;
tf=1;
x0=numpy.array([0]);
def F(t,x): return t**2;

x=scipy.integrate.RK23(F,t0,x0,tf)
```

Comment: Provide us with some working/tried code. Currently it's all speculative what you have and what you are solving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RK23`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK23.html) is a class that implements a way to solve an ODE, that is, it is an [`OdeSolver`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.integrate.OdeSolver.html#scipy.integrate.OdeSolver) so it should not be used directly but in other functions like [`solve_ivp`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html):

```
import numpy
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp, RK23
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t0=0
tf=1

x0=numpy.array([0])

def F(t,x): return t**2

sol = solve_ivp(F, [t0, tf], x0, RK23)
print(sol)
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0])
plt.show()
```

OdeSolver allows the developer to add custom methods without the need to rewrite scipy, but since RK23 is a classic method already implemented by scipy, you could pass just the name and scipy search for the appropriate class:

```
...
sol = solve_ivp(F, [t0, tf], x0, "RK23")
...
```